# Зачем и в каких конкретно случаях нужно использовать HashMap, если мы можем сделать тоже самое используя HashSet?

Tags: java, map, коллекции, множества

Есть простой класс:

```
public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Person(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [age=" + age + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
```

Есть еще один класс:

```
public class Item<K,P> {
    private K key;
    private P person;
    public Item(K key, P person) {
        this.key = key;
        this.person = person;
    }
    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(K key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public P getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    public void setPerson(P person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [key=" + key + ", person=" + person + "]";
    }


}
```

ГДЕ ПРАВДА???

И сама реализация классов:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Item<Integer, Person>> set = new HashSet<Item<Integer, Person>>();

        set.add(new Item<Integer, Person>(1, new Person(23, "gogo")));
        set.add(new Item<Integer, Person>(2, new Person(42, "niko")));
        set.add(new Item<Integer, Person>(3, new Person(32, "toto")));

        Iterator<Item<Integer, Person>> iter = set.iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iter.next());

        }

        Map<Integer, Person> map = new HashMap<Integer, Person>();

        map.put(1, new Person(12, "anton"));
        map.put(2, new Person(42, "valera"));
        map.put(3, new Person(41, "vova"));

        Iterator iter1 = map.entrySet().iterator();

        while (iter1.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iter1.next());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Для нормального отображения кода в вопросе/ответе, выделите его в редакторе и воспользуйтесь иконкой `{}`

Comment: Я думаю кто-нибудь ответит на этот вопрос, а пока можете почитать это: http://devcolibri.com/4385 Как по факту, внутреннее устройство этих коллекций и способ хранения очень сильно отличается.

Comment: спасибо за внимание и ссылку)

Comment: Как вы значение из сета получите, кроме перебора?

Comment: @TagirValeev, черт.

Comment: хотелось бы узнать по чему?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это принципиально разные структуры данных и используются они для разных целей.

`Set` - это [множество](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE), то самое математическое множество. И соответственно использовать его надо как множество, т.е. хранить набор ***уникальных*** элементов.

`Map` - это [ассоциированный массив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2), который хранит пары ключ-значение, где ключ должен быть ***уникальным***, а значение нет.

Соответственно выбор правильной структуры надо делать на основе того какие действия над этими данными вы собираетесь делать. Если только хранить набор ***уникальных*** значений и проверять, что такое значение уже есть в структуре данных, то это `Set`. Если вам необходимо периодически искать значение по ключу(например по ИД), то это `Map`.

Если же вам надо хранить просто список объектов и периодически проходить по всем элементам этого списка(как в ваших примерах), то надо использовать `List`.

Относительно вопроса о временах операций, есть такие замечательные ссылки, где все хорошо описано

для Java: https://github.com/benblack86/java-snippets/blob/master/resources/java_collections.pdf

для Абстракций: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Все они приведены в терминах Big-O нотаций, что это в принципе такое, можно почитать [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABO%C2%BB_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%C2%ABo%C2%BB_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5).

Comment: set сам по себе работает по принципу map, кличи уникальные, а значения по умолчанию void или null.                                                                Я хотел бы увидеть пример, если это возможно, где использование Map было бы просто необходимо, то есть пример где я бы НЕ смог реализовать задачу используя Set + Generic класс (как описывалось више).                                                                                                             Спасибо)

Comment: @MukolaShorobura У `Set` нет такого понятия как ключ в принципе. Это математическая абстракция, её описание можно найти по ссылке в ответе.

Comment: @MukolaShorobura Вам уже раза 3 сказали, так что я только повторю, взять значение по ключу из `Set` невозможно, т.к. там нет такого понятия и соответственно метода тоже нет.

Comment: согласен, не ключи, а значения, но все же эти значения можно реализовать как "ключи" к такой "мапе", которую я описывал выше?

Comment: Set<Item<Integer, Person>> set = new HashSet<Item<Integer, Person>>();

  set.add(new Item<Integer, Person>(1, new Person(23, "gogo")));
  set.add(new Item<Integer, Person>(2, new Person(42, "niko")));
  set.add(new Item<Integer, Person>(3, new Person(32, "toto"))); 

  
  for (Item<Integer, Person> item : set) {
   if(item.getKey().equals(2)){
    System.out.println(item.getPerson());
   }
  }

Comment: @MukolaShorobura да так можно сделать, но это уже операция поиска, а не взятие по ключу и по времени она будет занимать принципиально другое время(O(n) против O(1)). Вообще надо понимать, что структуры данных были придуманы для упрощения разных операция, а не для придумывания принципиально новых или удаление старых. В любой структуре можно искать-добавлять-удалять и т.д., но где-то это сделать проще, где-то сложнее.

Comment: хорошо, теперь понял)                                                                                  Если не трудно, объясните какие есть вот эти относительные времена и чем они отличаются?

Answer (score 2):

Обход всех элементов `Map` — не самая нужная операция. Самая популярная и важная — быстро получить значение по ключу. Для такого сценария ваш `Set` не годится: вы не можете это сделать эффективно (не перебирая все ключи). Поэтому `Map` нужен.

Уместнее обратный вопрос: зачем `HashSet<Key>`, если его можно реализовать, например, через `HashMap<Key, Void>` и получить действительно все операции? По факту `HashSet` примерно так и реализован (он внутри хранит `HashMap`). Существует он отдельным классом по большей части для удобства.

Также замечу, что ваш `Item` реализован неправильно: даже в вашем сценарии вы не исключаете одинаковый элементов в `Set` (у вас используется `Object.equals` и `Object.hashCode` по умолчанию, соответственно элементы сравниваются по reference equality).

Comment: а если в классе Item переопределить методы equals и hashCode конкретно для поля key?

Comment: @MukolaShorobura ничего не измениться, hash и equals должны быть переопределены именно у того класса, экземпляры которого вы добавляете в `Set`. Вы можете их переопределить так, чтобы вызывался hash и equals полей key, но это всё равно надо написать явно.

Comment: @MukolaShorobura, ну даже таким образом вы никак не получите уже добавленное значение без явного обхода всех значений. У `Set` же нету метода типа `get`. Максимум вы сможете проверить, существует ли элемент с таким ключом, но какое значение ему соответствует, вы не узнаете.

Comment: может я что - то не понимаю, извините) ну а так:                                        Set<Item<Integer, Person>> set = new HashSet<Item<Integer, Person>>();

  set.add(new Item<Integer, Person>(1, new Person(23, "gogo")));
  set.add(new Item<Integer, Person>(2, new Person(42, "niko")));
  set.add(new Item<Integer, Person>(3, new Person(32, "toto"))); 

  
  for (Item<Integer, Person> item : set) {
   if(item.getKey().equals(2)){
    System.out.println(item.getPerson());
   }
  }

Comment: @MukolaShorobura я же говорю, вы делаете обход всех элементов. А идея в том, чтобы обойтись без обхода. Если у вас миллион элементов, вы так же будете поступать? Если вас на каждую операцию обход не смущает, то вам и `Set` не нужен, всё можно на `ArrayList` сделать.